# Post your question still grayed out

Tags: support, asking-questions

Last year, people were posting about the same problem and it was reported to be fixed.     But I'm having the problem with another post today.    The problem seems to be that I'm supposed to first review my question but there's no button for reviewing the question.    Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is this question on Meta the same as yours? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351197/307535

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this.     Looks like the same issue.     I opened another instance of my browser, and there was my question sitting there, with `Review Question` waiting for me.    I reviewed and posted, and all is well for now.    But it would be nice if the problem could be fixed.